# create async method that calulate the sum and limit numbers of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-3.0

I'm trying to create a async method in my c# application and want to make it with limited threads the method should calculate the  sum of many arrays each array in separate threads, but if we have more than 4 like 6 arrays, first you run 4
threads and once a thread is released you need to run one more and so on.

this is my code :

```
static int CalculateRouter(Route route)
        {
            int total = route.sum(route.routers);
            return total;
        }
```

Async method that calculates best route asynchronously by calculating total time
required for each route in a separate thread.

```
 public async Task <int> AsyncBestRoute(List<Route> Routes)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
            foreach (var route in Routes)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CalculateRouter(route)));
            }
            int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            int minValue = results.Min();
            Console.WriteLine(minValue);
            Console.WriteLine("********************");

            return await Task.FromResult(minValue);
        }
```

is my work are correct in the method ? and how i can but limits of threads ? it's my first time to work within it and don't know how i should delay with it, there's any help or idea ?

Comment: Have you looked into Parallel.ForEach and Parallel.Invoke?

Comment: You can also look into Parallel LINQ (PLINQ) which also supports concurrency limits.

Comment: can u say more please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a async method in my c# application and want to make it with limited threads the method should calculate the sum of many arrays each array in separate threads, but if we have more than 4 like 6 arrays, first you run 4 threads and once a thread is released you need to run one more and so on.

First: asynchrony is quite different than parallelism, although they're both forms of concurrency. The whole point of asynchrony is to use *fewer* threads, and parallelism is to use *more* threads.

Since you're dealing with a CPU-bound operation (summing values), you want parallelism, not asynchrony. `Parallel` and PLINQ are the appropriate tools here. Generally, PLINQ is a bit cleaner if you have a result (or sequence of results). Both `Parallel` and PLINQ support limiting the number of threads.

```
public int BestRoute(List<Route> Routes)
{
  return Routes.AsParallel()
      .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
      .Select(CalculateRouter)
      .Min();
}
```

If you *also* need asynchrony, e.g., if you need to free up the UI thread, then you can use `await` and `Task.Run` as such:

```
// Run BestRoute on a thread pool thread to avoid blocking the UI
var minValue = await Task.Run(() => BestRoute(routes));
```

Comment: i tried to run in main class as  `            var minValue = await Task.Run(() => RouteSyncAndAsyncMethods.BestRoute(Routes));
`   
**RouteSyncAndAsyncMethods** is the object from class, but it's not working why ?

Comment: @TaliaDianal: Beats me. What's your error message?